# Refer to an individual JTextField when they're in different tabs

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, jtabbedpane

I have three JTextFields, when the buy button is pressed the associated listener should retrieve the text from the text fields and use it to update the table.

[image]

The issue is that when I press the buy button it tries to use the data in the JTextFields in David's tab as opposed to the one I'm currently on. If I made another tab named "Jack" it would then try to be using jacks. The code to create the text boxes is as follows:

```
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Name Of Share:");                                       
    tabPanel.add(label2);
    textFieldName = new JTextField("", 15); 

    textFieldName.setColumns(10);
    textFieldName.setToolTipText("Enter Number of shares here");
    tabPanel.add(textFieldName);
```

The listener for the buy button:

```
int quantity = 0;
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Buy")) {
        String name = view.getTextFieldName().getText();
        String ticker = view.getTextFieldTicker().getText().toUpperCase();
        try{
         quantity = Integer.parseInt(view.getTextFieldNumber().getText());
        }catch(NumberFormatException er){

        }

        view.buy(ticker, name, quantity);
    }
```

Everything works fine if I only have one tab but once I introduce more that's when the issues start.

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this so I can get data from the text boxes of only the tab I am on?

I should have mentioned view is of type MainGUI a Class I have created, which is used for building the GUI which has the fields:

```
public class MainGUI extends JFrame implements Observer {

private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
private JTable table;
private JTextField textFieldTicker;
private JTextField textFieldName;
private JTextField textFieldNumber;
private DefaultTableModel model;
private PortfolioManager pm;
private JLabel tValue;
```

to create a Tab the code used is:

```
JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();

    JSplitPane splitPanelbtm = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, labelPanel, buttonPanel);
    JSplitPane splitPanel = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, topPanel, splitPanelbtm){
        private final int location = 500;
        {setDividerLocation(location);}
        @Override
        public int getDividerLocation(){
            return location;
        }
        @Override
        public int getLastDividerLocation(){
            return location;
        }
    };

    splitPanel.setEnabled( false );
    splitPanel.setDividerSize(0);
    splitPanelbtm.setEnabled( false );
    splitPanelbtm.setDividerSize(0);
    splitPanelbtm.setBorder(null);
    splitPanel.setBorder(null);
    tabbedPane.add(tabName, splitPanel);
    tabbedPane.setName(tabName);
    this.add(tabbedPane);
    this.setVisible(true);

    createLabelsButtons(topPanel);
    createTable(topPanel);
    tValue = new JLabel("Total Value for " + tabbedPane.getName() + " is: $ ");
    labelPanel.add(tValue);
    createTabButtons(buttonPanel);
```

Comment: what exactly is the type of `view`? and why would it have a `buy` method (unless it's an object you created, then nevermind)

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: It's impossible to help with so few code. But you should have two different instances of the same JPanel class, one per tab. I don't see how an instance of a component could be able to use an the text fields of the other instance. If you want help, post a complete, minimal example.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, hopefully those extra details will help. To access the JTextFields from the listener I have created three getters for the "view" the MainGUI class. Is this likely to be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried creating a listener to track when you change tabs?